# How to check does user type something in iframe (external domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, keypress

I build an app where user type voucher code into form and then we show them booking widget in iframe (external domain)

My problem is because I don't know does user complete reservation to mark voucher in the database as used.
I know I can't access iframe HTML but is there any way to check when user type something because if type something that means he is on the last step - type personal details.

My question:
Is there any way to find out does user typing something at his keyboard if the form is in an iframe?

I don't want to steal any user data! Is there any other way I can check what happend in iframe? Take Screenshoot option?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry It is not possible,because cross-origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few alternatives for you. Typically you cannot access the `iframe` for security reasons, however, if the external domain is owned by you or agrees to cooperate there are ways of making this work.

One option is Cross-window messaging. It allows for you to send messages to the domain and for them to respond. The catch here is that they need to respond and therefore you need them to cooperate. You can read more about it here: https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication#cross-window-messaging

Another alternative is to allow cross-origin `iframe` elements to be accessed. This can be done with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). Again, this is something that the external domain owner needs to implement. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: sound crazy but if I run my widget with some software which dont block CORS and take a screen and send that to user browser window - record screen on my PC and send as a video to user browser, then take mouse coordinates from there and keys and return to my PC again :) ???